# Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row:

Tags: sql

a foreign key constraint fails (`ldatabase`.`book`, CONSTRAINT `bpid` FOREIGN KEY (`bpid`) REFERENCES `publish` (`pid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
INSERT INTO `ldatabase`.`book` (`bid`, `title`, `author`, `bpid`, `available`, `language`) VALUES (20, 'dsp', 'kevin', 01, 10, 'eng')

i have created the tables and also inserted values into the publish table.. when i am trying enter values for book table .. due to my misfortune i have encountered this error

Comment: a foreign key constraint fails (`ldatabase`.`book`, CONSTRAINT `bpid` FOREIGN KEY (`bpid`) REFERENCES `publish` (`pid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) plz.. help me out with this issue

Comment: Please post more information. Can you post your create table statement for each of the two tables?

Comment: And the line of code that's causing the problem. I have a feeling there is an `INSERT` statement that is failing?

Comment: Ok thank you very much i got my error solved..

Answer (score 0):

Posted error indicates that, column `bpid` in table `ldatabase.book` has a foreign key relationship with `publish` table `pid` column.

Which means, before you insert any `bpid` key in `book` table make sure that the same key (`pid`) already exists in `publish` table else you will end up with the above posted error.

Comment: Great. Do consider accepting the answer if it's helpful.